# How to fix angular datepicker filter

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to filter the date which where the FROM and TO will display the data,

but when the FROM and TO are the same it doesn't display the current date selected.

Example ***FROM: 08-01-2019 00:00:00*** | ***To: 08-29-2019 13:00:00***
it doesn't display the data **2019-08-28 12:36:01**, but when I try to set the ***FROM: 06-14-2019 00:00:00 | TO: 08-29-2019 13:00:00*** it displays all the data

**templog.component.ts**

```
columnDefs: any = [
    { headerName: 'Date Time', field: 'dateandtime' },
    { headerName: 'Location', field: 'sensor' },
    { headerName: 'Temperature', field: 'temperature' },
    { headerName: 'Humidity', field: 'humidity' }
  ];

submitForm(): void {
    this.rowData = record.default.records;

    const dateStart = format(this.validateForm.value.datePickerStart, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    const dateEnd = format(this.validateForm.value.datePickerEnd, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    
    for(let i = 0;i < this.rowData.length; i++){
      if (isBefore(this.rowData[i].dateandtime, dateStart) || 
        isAfter(this.rowData[i].dateandtime, dateEnd )) {  
          this.rowData = this.rowData.splice(i, 0);
      }
    }    
  }
```

**templog.json**

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 01:38:02",
            "sensor": "Sewing Line1",
            "temperature": "25.8",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 01:36:01",
            "sensor": "Sewing Line1",
            "temperature": "25.8",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 01:36:01",
            "sensor": "Heat Seal Area",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2019-08-28 12:36:01",
            "sensor": "Heat Seal Area",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: When you need to remove multiple items in an array, you need to do it from the last index. If you do it from the front, once you removed an item, the next item will replace the current index. Or you can do `i--` after removal.

Comment: Or simply use `filter`

Comment: @Icycool thank you sir. but I already tried on it. still it doesn't work.

Comment: @Random where I will apply the "filter"?

Comment: @ABC please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loops can be simplified with a `filter`

```
export interface MyRecord {
    dateandtime: string,
    sensor: string,
    temperature: string,
    humidity: string
}

public rowData: MyRecord[] = [];

submitForm(): void {
  this.rowData = record.default.records;

  const dateStart = format(this.validateForm.value.datePickerStart, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
  const dateEnd = format(this.validateForm.value.datePickerEnd, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

  this.rowData = this.rowData.filter((data: MyRecord) => {
    // keep data which are not out of date-bound
    return !isBefore(data.dateandtime, dateStart) && !isAfter(data.dateandtime, dateEnd);
  });  
}
```

Comment: Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)  - should I set the data as any? or (data: { dateandtime: string | number | Date; })?

Comment: is `rowData` typed ? If so, data has the same type (removing the array). If `rowData: MySuperType[]`, then `data: MySuperType`.

Comment: because I set the rowData: any = []; then this.rowData = record.default.records; where it will get the data inside the templog.json.

Comment: (data: this.rowData) it doesn't work. it should get the data of rowData

Comment: @ABC ok, I'll add how to use types too since you seem not to fully understand how it works

Comment: No problem, the goal is to be able to fully understand the answer :)

Comment: I already add export interface MyRecord in templog.component.ts but there's an error which is 'MyRecord' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198667/discussion-between-random-and-abc).

Answer (score 0):

> *Resolved*

Earlier you were saying  ***FROM: 08-29-2019 00:00:00 To: 08-29-2019 13:00:00 it doesn't display the data 2019-08-28 12:36:01*** which is true. Because ***2019-08-28 12:36:01*** is not between those range.

And now since you have updated the question, if you want to filter mentioned date please follow below simple JavaScript solution, you can convert it to angular.

```
var data=[
    {
        "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 01:38:02",
        "sensor": "Sewing Line1",
        "temperature": "25.8",
        "humidity": "99.9"
    },
    {
        "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 01:36:01",
        "sensor": "Sewing Line1",
        "temperature": "25.8",
        "humidity": "99.9"
    },
    {
        "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 01:36:01",
        "sensor": "Heat Seal Area",
        "temperature": "25.9",
        "humidity": "99.9"
    },
    {
        "dateandtime": "2019-08-28 12:36:01",
        "sensor": "Heat Seal Area",
        "temperature": "25.9",
        "humidity": "99.9"
    }
]
data.filter(function(x){ 
                    if(new Date(x.dateandtime)> new Date('06-12-2019 00:00:00') 
                    && new Date(x.dateandtime)< new Date('08-28-2019 14:00:00')){ return x }
      })
```

Comment: indeed, the error comes from the test, good catch. But please do not use `function(x)`, use arrow functions (`x =>`) instead...

Comment: Sir I'm using isBefore and isAfter

Comment: ok sir. I already edit my question FROM: 08-01-2019 TO: 08-29-2019. sorry for mistake. but when i try it to run it doesn't show on my code

Comment: @ABC I couldn't see you mentioned anything about moment.js. I belive isBefore and isAfter are moment.js functions. But anyways try testing with inbetween date range and see. It should work.

Comment: but it works when the range is june 14, 2018 - august 29,2019 the will display